# Add params to URL if page gets reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyho, I want to add GET params like?USER_NAME=Max&USER_ID=01 to the URL if the page gets reloaded. I already got a few snippets for changing the URL / adding params. But I need something to detect the page reload and execute a function. Or a way to change the path of the Url directly if the page gets reloaded.

I tried several things like `beforeunload` and `navigation` types.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    // EDIT: vars like uname etc are defined
    var newurlgetstring = "?USER_NAME=" + uname + "&USER_EMAIL=" + uemail + "&LAST_NAME=" + lname + "&PRE_NAME=" + fname + "&UTITEL=" + utitel + "&U_ID_T=" + uidt + "&MV=" + mv + "&V=" + uv ;
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +window.location.pathname + newurlgetstring;
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
});
```

But I want able to execute a function with `beforeunload`. I was just able to display a return question.

Comment: What is `newurlgetstring`, is it function or just a variable? @Cleee

Comment: I don't think the browser allows you to redirect inside a beforeunload, otherwise you could be able to force the user to not leave your page. What you could do is store a value inside the localstore or cookies on beforeunload and then on load retrieve it, if it is there add those values to the url

Comment: its a var with the GET Params

Comment: Be aware that `beforeunload` gets fired whenever page navigation occurs or when window/tab is closed, not just on reloads.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @phuzi yes but first i want to know if there is a possibility to execute a fuction before the reload. After that i try to specify the functions only for reloads.

Comment: @Wimanicesir this is a good questions and could be the point :D i try to make the system more safe. im writing a e learning system and have to transmit a few values via GET params. These params are important for the system because they include the current number of trials and the maximum number of trials. I want knowbody to change them. Thats why i am deleting the get params from url when the page is called.

Comment: "I want knowbody to change them." ...in that case, store them server-side, associated with the user's identity. Anything you do in the browser is subject to interference by the user. Even if you managed to achieve what you wanted using JavaScript, someone could just turn that off, or remove that bit of code from the page before continuing. They could also try using a non-browser HTTP client such as PostMan, and make any requests they like, without JavaScript getting in the way. Ultimately, you cannot use your browser code to implement any security or validation

Comment: ...contd: (Well, you can, in order to enhance user experience and reduce round-trips to the server, but you can't _rely_ on it. Anything which comes to the server from the client must be validated by the server to ensure that the supplied data is correct, is not malicious, and that the user is actually authorised to perform the requested action.)

Comment: But its not only about the safety. For the safety i could write an query if the get params compare with the data in db. I also dont want to have the get params in the browser history to prevent mistakes if the user use a link in his browser histoy to open the quiz.

Comment: Well again, your application should not rely on user/browser-supplied parameters in order to determine the current state of the quiz. Store the state of the quiz server-side in the DB after each time they submit, and then restore it from the DB next time they request to open the quiz. This is not so much about safety, but it is about validation. You seem to be passing the username on the querystring even...instead make the user log in, store a session variable to indicate that they've logged in, and then use that to know who the current user is.

Comment: i am storing the date in a db after they submit. Then im restoring them at the quiz page. But i am trying to combine a normal cms with an e learning software. And the only given way from that software is to transmit datas from the cms to the elearning software via get params.

Comment: " i am trying to combine a normal cms with an e learning software"...that might be your first mistake then. Why did you do that? CMS is pretty unsuitable for this type of application. You mean it's something already existing that you are forced to integrate with, perhaps?

Comment: You'd be better to try and share session or use a shared identity provider to pass the user identity from one to the other, so you can achieve a form of single sign-on. Or just force the user to log in separately to the e-learning portal. As you've now discovered, passing identifying values on the querystring is inherently insecure.

Comment: Maybe. I am using iSpring QuizMaker. The Quizmaker generates me an html / css / js output with the quiz validations and so on.. When the Quiz is finished it is communicating with a .php on my server to store the results in DB.  f.e.  I also added more stuff like pdf gen for the certificate and a php mailer. The only thing i want to manage with the CMS are the userdatas and the Content Management of the system. And the userdatas plus the number of trials are transmitted via GET params.

Comment: Is the CMS already existing and you are forced to use it? If not, then I would say get rid of it. User management is not the main advantage of a CMS. And creating login and user identity functionality with PHP is not too hard. You can find examples online. Or if you're using a PHP framework (e.g. Laravel or one of those) then they often come with that kind of functionality built-in and ready to go, without need of a separate CMS or other kind of application.

Comment: The other alternative is to try and integrate your PHP fully into the CMS - e.g. maybe it supports adding extra functionality in the form of a plugin or extension, and then you'd likely to be able to take advantage properly of the CMS's user functionality so you could access the current user's session directly from your quiz code, without relying on the querystring parameters. You'd have to investigate what the CMS is capable of. But mostly I think the CMS is likely to be a big white elephant, if all you're using it for is logging users in.

Comment: The CMS is not only for the User Management. 90% of the Content are normal Content like videos, images, infographics or normal text. Just 10% are the quizzes like an learning success control. And the quiz system is based on js. Only the commucation with the server is based on php. So if I would use an PHP Framework or an basic login functionality i would need to transmit the userdata via get params too i guess.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you integrate the PHP properly with the CMS then you could just change the generated quiz files into .PHP and put some includes at the top to make them PHP-aware, and they can then potentially be part of your CMS plugin. Then they can be protected by login etc. And then the AJAX requests which the quiz page executes...when the request arrives at the server you can check the current user identity, verify the quiz ID etc and thus be able to validate the data.

Comment: This is the long term plan. But yeah maybe i should focus it more and spend more time on it. thanks dude!